# Google CSE with a custom form

Tags: php, html, forms, search-engine, google-custom-search

I have a GET form at the top of my page, but it is not yet configured. All I have for it is this:

```
    <div class="top-search">
        <form  method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
            <div>
                <input type="text" value="Search..." name="s" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=" " />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

How can I manipulate this to use Google CSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeming as no one decided to answer it, I found out for myself.

```
    <div class="top-search">
        <form id="searchform" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="xxxx" />
                <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
                <input type="text" value="" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" name="sa" value=" " />
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Where "xxxx" is your Search Engine Unique ID, found on the Basics page of your control panel.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a great start. Google cse seems like a logical option for any site, seeing as google index your site. It just such a shame that the outputted code is a mine field. Now I need to disassociate the stylesheets